# TypeError: Not a buffer node.js crypto, aws-sdk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to create an S3 policy for uploads to amazon s3... but when encoding the policy, I get a type error: not a buffer. I am using crypto version: 0.0.3 and aws-sdk version:2.0.0-rc.19

This was working before so I assume it might have something to do with the update to the aws-sdk...

Here is the code. The comment will show where the error occurs:

```
createS3Policy = function(contentType, callback) {
    var date = new Date();
    var s3Policy = {
        'expiration': getExpiryTime(),
        'conditions': [
            ['starts-with', '$key', 'shimmy-assets/'],
            {'bucket': S3_BUCKET},
            {'acl': 'public-read'},
            ['starts-with', '$Content-Type', contentType],
            {'success_action_status' : '201'}
        ]
    };

    // stringify and encode the policy
    var stringPolicy = JSON.stringify(s3Policy);
    console.log('string policy: ' + stringPolicy);
    var base64Policy = new Buffer(stringPolicy, 'utf-8').toString('base64');

    // sign the base64 encoded policy
    // NOT A BUFFER ERROR HERE
    var signature = crypto.createHmac('sha1', AWS_SECRET_KEY).update(new Buffer(base64Policy, 'utf-8')).digest('base64');          

    // build the results object
    var s3Credentials = {
        s3Policy: base64Policy,
        s3Signature: signature,
        AWSAccessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY
    };

    // send it back
    callback(s3Credentials);
};
```

Comment: What is the definition of `AWS_SECRET_KEY`? Is it a `Buffer`?

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=406141

Answer (score 2):

Just got the same problem, so here is my working code:

I use the following function to calculate hmac;

```
function hmac(algorithm, key, text, encoding) {
    var hmac = crypto.createHmac(algorithm, key);

    hmac.setEncoding(encoding);
    hmac.write(text);
    hmac.end();

    return hmac.read();
};
```

So my signature is:

```
var signature = hmac(
    'sha1',
    secretAccessKey, //Line A
    new Buffer(JSON.stringify(policy)).toString('base64')), //Line B
    'base64');
```

Make sure that Line A and Line B are not undefined. Even secretAccessKey being a string it will throw `NOT A BUFFER` error in case it is undefined!